# In “showing # of # items” how to set/get the total count in 2nd'#' on a default pagination in laravel

Tags: pagination, laravel-5

I'm using laravel default pagination. Here I got the result count like 'showing # of # items' in the top of a page. It shows only the count of that page, but I need Now: 'Showing 1 to 5 of 5 entries' To: Showing 1 to 5 of 10 entries

In controller,

```
$variable = DB::Orderby('created_at','desc')->paginate(5);
```

Please help me to get wanted result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation with this link:- https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination
If you want to show the Results you need to do this:-

```
<span>{{ $variable->firstItem() }} to {{ $variable->lastItem() }}</span> of 
<span>{{ $variable->total() }}</span>
```

It will give your expected output.
If yo want to show the paginate Link use this in balde:-

```
{{ $variable ->links() }}
```

Hope it Helps!

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. If it's custom display your code very useful. But I got this automatically while adding the pagination. I didn't write any code for this. If used this above code, shall I hide the default one?